# Searching Office 365 Mail via API

Tags: ms-office, preview

I would like to use the Office 365 API to search for email. Is this possible?

I have had a look at the online documentation ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605901(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605901%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) but can't see search.

Cheers
Tony

Comment: Tony, you're going to have to give a bit more something before you get any help.  What DID you find?  Nobody here is going to search the documentation for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use $filter, which is briefly documented on the MSDN page you referenced above, and is more thoroughly documented in the [OData Version 4.0 Part 2 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html).